# Adding more data to MSSQL database using VBScript

Tags: sql-server, vbscript

I have the code:

```
Dim conn, SQL, rs
    Const DB_CONNECT_STRING = "Provider = SQLOLEDB.1; Data Source = DJ-PC; Initial Catalog = Baza_NC; user id = 'user_baza_nc'; password = 'Password1'"
    Set myConn = CreateObject ( "ADODB.Connection")
    Set MyCommand = CreateObject ( "ADODB.Command")
    myConn.Open DB_CONNECT_STRING
    Set myCommand.ActiveConnection = myConn

    myCommand.CommandText = "UPDATE Klienci_NC SET Klienci_NC.Klient = '" & & Klient_niceform' 'WHERE Klienci_NC.ID =' "& ID_zmienna &" ' "

    myCommand.Execute
    myConn.Close
```

I would like to write to MSSQL database further data relating to the address in the column "Klienci_NC.adres" using & Adres_niceform &
the VBScript looks like this:

```
myCommand.CommandText = "UPDATE Klienci_NC SET Klienci_NC.adres = '" & & Adres_niceform' 'WHERE Klienci_NC.ID =' "& ID_zmienna &" ' "
```

however, using

```
Dim conn, SQL, rs
    Const DB_CONNECT_STRING = "Provider = SQLOLEDB.1; Data Source = DJ-PC; Initial Catalog = Baza_NC; user id = 'user_baza_nc'; password = 'Password1'"
    Set myConn = CreateObject ( "ADODB.Connection")
    Set MyCommand = CreateObject ( "ADODB.Command")
    myConn.Open DB_CONNECT_STRING
    Set myCommand.ActiveConnection = myConn

    myCommand.CommandText = "UPDATE Klienci_NC SET Klienci_NC.Klient = '" & & Klient_niceform' 'WHERE Klienci_NC.ID =' "& ID_zmienna &" ' "

    myCommand.CommandText = "UPDATE Klienci_NC SET Klienci_NC.adres = '" & & Adres_niceform' 'WHERE Klienci_NC.ID =' "& ID_zmienna &" ' "

    myCommand.Execute
    myConn.Close
```

It is performed only the first line:

myCommand.CommandText = "UPDATE Klienci_NC SET Klienci_NC.Klient = '" & & Klient_niceform' 'WHERE Klienci_NC.ID =' "& ID_zmienna &" ' "

How to join the script:

```
myCommand.CommandText = "UPDATE Klienci_NC SET Klienci_NC.adres = '" & & Adres_niceform' 'WHERE Klienci_NC.ID =' "& ID_zmienna &" ' "
```

the two worked properly?

Comment: You can use several items in the set clause like this: `update table set col1 = val1, col2 = val2 where ...` but your code is possibly also vulnerable to SQL injection attacks and you should use ADODB command parameters to inject the values instead of raw concatenation. I don't quite remember the proper syntax though (which is why this is a comment and not an answer).

Answer (score 1):

Combine both statements?

```
myCommand.CommandText = "UPDATE Klienci_NC SET Klienci_NC.Klient = '" & Klient_niceform  & "',Klienci_NC.adres = '" & Adres_niceform &"' WHERE Klienci_NC.ID ='" & ID_zmienna &"'"
```

Comment: I agree with jpw regarding SQL Injection, however, if you really want to build the string, you may want to trap possible single quotes.  For example:  replace(Klient_niceform,"'","''")

Comment: Single quote replacement is nowhere good enough to prevent sql injection. It does at least allow for actual data that includes a single quote to work though.

Comment: No argument from me here.  Trapping the single quote was my immediate concern.  If he is committed to building the string, I didn't want him chasing a ghost.